# How to get single character after space?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, cut

How can I get below output? I want the first field as it is and a single character after space.

```
echo "Hello world"
Hellow
```

If it also has a 3rd field than the beginning character of the 3rd field should be in the output.

```
echo "hello world unix"
hellou
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk` to output the first whitespace-delimited word concatenated with the first character of the last whitespace-delimited word:

```
awk '{ print $1 substr($NF, 1, 1) }'
```

The `substr()` function returns a number of characters from a given position of a string, and `$1` and `$NF` is the first and last whitespace-delimited word on the current line, respectively.

Testing:

```
$ echo 'hello world' | awk '{ print $1 substr($NF, 1, 1) }'
hellow
```

```
$ echo 'apple beet carrot' | awk '{ print $1 substr($NF, 1, 1) }'
applec
```

Comment: Will not this duplicated the first letter of a word for a line with that single word only?

Comment: @αғsнιη Yes it would. The question does not specify what should happen in the case when there is only a single word.

Answer (score 6):

**With sed:**

**Edit:** improved by [glenn jackmann](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman), thanks!

```
$ echo "Hello world" | sed -E 's/(\S+).*\s(\S).*$/\1\2/'
Hellow
$ echo "hello world unix" | sed -E 's/(\S+).*\s(\S).*$/\1\2/'
hellou
```

Description with "hello world unix" as example:

- `s/` substitute the following pattern
- `(\S+)` 1st group, one or more non-space characters: "hello"
- `.*` the middle part, any characters: " world"
- `\s` space character: " "
- `(\S)` 2nd group, non-space character: "u"
- `.*$` any characters up to the end: "nix"
- `/\1\2/` replace with 1st and 2nd group: "hellou"

**With bash:**

```
$ var="Hello world"
$ var_end=${var##* };echo ${var%% *}${var_end:0:1}
Hellow

$ var="hello world unix"
$ var_end=${var##* };echo ${var%% *}${var_end:0:1}
hellou
```

Description with "hello world unix" as example:

- `var_end=${var##* }` remove matching prefix pattern, longest match,
  "hello world ", result: "unix"
- `${var%% *}` remove matching suffix pattern, longest match,
  " world unix", result: "hello"
- `${var_end:0:1}` get the first character: "u"

Comment: Your regex can be a bit simpler: you don't need to capture the 2nd group, and it can contain any characters: `^(\S+).*\s(\S)` will do. Also, I believe the perl-like regex means you must use GNU sed.

Answer (score 3):

Using bash:

```
text="hello world unix"
if [[ $text =~ ^([^[:space:]]+).*[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]) ]]; then
    declare -p BASH_REMATCH
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH='([0]="hello world u" [1]="hello" [2]="u")'
hellou
```

Comment: just curious to understand to know, why is `declare -p` needed here? The array is already populated right?

Comment: It's not needed at all. Merely to show the contents of the array, to see the results of the regex match with capturing parentheses.